# how to set Sessions when log in using Passport and Express in order to req.user._id?

Tags: node.js, session, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have already a MEAN app based in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uONz0lEWft0&t=113s (Great one by the way).

The functionality includes: register, login, Authentication using Jwt Strategy and a Sessions.

To handle the Sessions it uses the front end (Angular2) to store the user credentials in the localStorage of the browser.

I personally I think this is a lack of security and as well I want to include a To Do list that belongs to a user, having two models 'users' and 'tasks' (one to many). That's why I need the current `user._id` as a reference. Example POST newTask:

```
var task = new Task({
    title: req.body.title,
    owner : req.user._id
});
```

I read another way to handle Sessions, storing the current user at the backend, using Passport. But even after reading the documentation I'm a little bit confused, perhaps you could answer my questions:

- Where should I include the `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` methods?
  I intuit that it must be when the user makes the log in, something like this:

  ```
  router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next)=> {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
  User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user)=>{
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
          return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
      }
      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) =>{
          if(err) throw err;
          if(isMatch){ ///------------- HERE ------------------
                  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
                  done(null, user.id);
                  });
                  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
                  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
                      done(err, user);
                  });
              });
              const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
                  expiresIn: 604800 //1 week
              });
              res.json({
                  success: true,
                  token:'JWT '+token,
                  user:{
                      id: user._id,
                      name: user.name,
                      username: user.username,
                      email: user.email
                  }
              });
          }else{
              return res.json({ success: false, msg:"wrong password"});
          }
      });
  });
  });
  ```
- Where is this session stored? (I'm using MongoDB)
- Is this enough to make a req.user from anywhere or should I include a middleware strategy or install dependencies such as 'express-session' or 'cookieParser', etc.. ?

Thank you beforehand.